# Python can't find PyGObject/gi even though it is installed

Tags: python, path, gtk, pygobject

I have trouble setting up the Python-Path for it, I don't really know what to do here. I use elementary OS, which should be similar enough to Ubuntu.

My code so far is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import gi
gi.require_version('GTK', '3.0')
```

When I run the script, the system reports that there is no module named "gi".
However, when I try

```
sudo apt-get python3-gi
```

I get told that it is installed already.
I tried

```
print(sys.path)
```

and

```
locate python3-gi
```

which gave me back some directories. But there were too many, so I don't know what, if this is at all the right way, to to copy where.

Addendum:

Okay, so doing `type export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python-gi3"` yields `export is a shell builtin
bash: type: PATH=/home/ge0rg/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/bin/python3-gi: not found`

`uname -r` yields `3.19.0-51-generic`.

In the meantime, I also tried reinstalling python3-gi, to no avail. Also, since python3-gi seems to b located in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-pacakges`, I tried going into python and doing `sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python3/dist-pacakges")` where the above mentioned folder was not included before. However, after doing this `import gi` gives the same error as before: `>>> import gi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'gi'`

EDIT: Also, `locate python3-gi` yields:

```
`/usr/share/doc/python3-gi
/usr/share/doc/python3-gi-cairo
/usr/share/doc/python3-gi/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/python3-gi/copyright
/usr/share/doc/python3-gi-cairo/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/python3-gi-cairo/copyright
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/python3-gi
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-gi-cairo.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-gi-cairo.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-gi-cairo.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-gi-cairo.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-gi-cairo.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-gi.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-gi.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-gi.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-gi.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-gi.prerm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-gi.shlibs`
```

however, `/usr/lib/dist-packages/gi` also exists, but `locate gi` just gives back a whole array of mostly unrelated results.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing its installed in  `/usr/local/bin/python-gi3` . If you see it there, open your shell and type type export `PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python-gi3"` to set the path

Comment: It is not there, but I found it (I think) in `/usr/share/doc/python3-gi`. But if I change your expression to `type export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python3-gi"` I get some listings of the path and :not found. I'm confused...

Comment: also, run cd / and then find . -name python-gi3

Comment: Ah okay, that's interesting. If I go find. -name python3-gi (not python-gi3, I hope that is what you mean, the other does not exist), I get `./home/ge0rg/anacona3/lib/python3.5/python3-gi`, `././usr/share/lintian/overrides/python3-gi`, `./usr/share/doc/python3-gi`.

Comment: But I believe the anaconda folder is just where I copied it to before without success. The error message if I try  `type export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python-gi3"`, even if I cange the folder to /home/anaconda3... or/usr/share..., I get the same error: `export is a bash bulitin. bash: type: PATH=[some listings of my paths, They don't fit in this comment...]. last line:/home/ge0rg/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/python-gi3: not found `

Comment: I still haven't solved the problem. I'm quite new to Linux and I'm not used to this stuff, so some helop would be really really appreciated!

Comment: can you post complete outputs of the find command the error from setting path and also run "  uname -r" which tells linux version. Do this in another reply or by editing your first post .